# How can I correctly "box" my strings so it doesn't look off?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a format thing in csharp, but my result comes as this:

```
                                ╔═══════════════════════════════╗
                                ║ Activation Status:  True║
                                ╚═══════════════════════════════╝
```

But I want it to be in the ║ at the end, my code is like this.

```
string isactive = data["IsActive"].ToString() // can be "true" or "false" 
                string border = $@"
                                    ╔═══════════════════════════════╗
                                    ║ Activation Status:  {isactive}║
                                    ╚═══════════════════════════════╝";
```

I also have different types of data such as Username (which can be around 5-10 characters) and other types of data which have different lengths of characters.

Comment: You'll have to keep track of the total length of your "box" and pad each line according to how long the data is.

Comment: Try string.PadRight. you will need to figure out the numbers according to your needs. You could actually pad both left and right. If you want a table look, you Kay want to see which string is the longest, and calculate based on that.

Comment: I tried to use string.PadRight but, calculating the lengths are kind of difficult.
I can get the data's length, but how do I calculate how much to pad it by so the end of the box is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having is that you may have many different strings of different lengths and you want them all to come out with a certain length.

The solution to this is [padding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padright?view=net-5.0). You can pad a string to a certain length by adding in empty characters if the string you want to pad is not that length:

```
string border = $@"
                                ╔═══════════════════════════════╗
                                ║ Activation Status:  {isactive.PadRight(10)}║
                                ╚═══════════════════════════════╝";
```

will make it so that if the string isn't 10 characters long, it will add spaces to the right until it is, making all the strings passed in 10 characters long which makes the box fit perfectly.

Comment: Hello, am looking into this, but where did you get 10 from?
I have other data, such as this 
https://ghostbin.com/paste/i0709
but doesn't seem to format properly

Comment: In your original string, you had `{isactive}` which you wanted to replace by something else. to make the box look correct, the number of characters has to stay the same as in `{isactive}`, which in this case is is 10, including the brackets.